# SQL trigger on Truncate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to Fire a trigger when you do TRUNCATE (instead deleted) in MSSQL

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx):

> TRUNCATE TABLE cannot activate a trigger because the operation does not log individual row deletions.

Comment: So if I have a transaction log table and want to log whenever a truncate is executed, or some kind of secondary data copy, which should be truncated whenever a truncate is called on the primary copy, this is impossible :-( There are so many reasons why a trigger on TRUNCATE would be useful, even if no individual rows can be provided in the trigger.

Answer (score 9):

You can't do this on SQL server.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx)

> TRUNCATE TABLE cannot activate a
>   trigger because the operation does not
>   log individual row deletions. For more
>   information, see CREATE TRIGGER
>   (Transact-SQL).

Answer (score 7):

Are you letting users run TRUNCATE TABLE ad hoc / willy nilly?  If not, instead of worrying about using a trigger, why not wrap the TRUNCATE command in a stored procedure that also deals with whatever the trigger would have done after the truncate finished?  (But you'd have to do it in the opposite order, of course.)